# Simple mobile redirect / deep link implementation

Tags: javascript, ios, redirect, deep-linking

So I have a redirect working, but it's a little janky & I'm hoping to make it less janky :)

I'm using deep linking to basically open the app only....nothing beyond that at the moment.

Below is the redirect for ios. It works ok, but it's throwing a URL error in safari that I have to tap to close before it will redirect to the app store. (This is the case of a user not having the app installed)

So...I know universal linking is what iOS9 is doing, but I'm trying to avoid implementing too much on the native code side. All I've done is add my custom URL scheme to the plist of the app.

So wise internet...is there a better way?

```
else if(isMobile.iOS())
{
   window.onload = function() {
        window.location = 'vrbhome://';
        setTimeout("window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vrb/id1066438072?ls=1&mt=8';", 1000);
    }


}
else  {
document.location.href="http://vrb.is";
}
```

Comment: Search for associated domains to open your app directly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is by (Apple's) design — the only way to work around it is to decrease the timeout enough that the user goes to the App Store before they have a chance to see the error. Unfortunately as of iOS 9.2, users with your app will also be redirected before they have a chance open the app. Universal Links are the solution Apple wishes you to use.

If you don't want to handle too much native code, you could try https://branch.io